# Get user ID from user Email with Ajax query

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have User ID with User Email with javascript on a click button action but unfortunately it doesnt work,

What am i doing wrong please ?

Here is the Javascript

( EDIT I MISSED A LINE )

```
(function($){
    $(document).on("click","#button_unsubscribe",function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/unsubscribe_user_id.php",
            data: { mail : $_GET('mail') },
            success: function(data){
                alert('user id = ' + data);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the php function ( more complex at the end but for now i'm blocking here)

```
<?php

$mail = $_REQUEST['mail'];
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $mail );
$userid = $user->ID;
echo $userid;

?>
```

Doesn't echo anything and return error 500

Thank you

Comment: You dont send any data to the `unsubscribe_user_id.php` file. and 500 is an internal server error so the `$_REQUEST['mail']` may be empty and PHP complains about it.

Comment: You need to add the GET-Parameter „mail“ to the url:  "/unsubscribe_user_id.php?mail=test@test.com"

Comment: Thank you, yes i do, if i echo the mail the data is correctly showing

Comment: Could you share the error log of 500?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find the trick i need to add some code line in the php file otherwise it seems he can't access to database

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
```

Cheers